# Proxy Server on FreeBSD is rejecting connections

Tags: freebsd, proxy, squid

I have done a proxy server on FreeBSD, but from my client the browser says that the server is **rejecting** connections. Here I leave you my `squid.conf` file.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sorry for the screenshots, but from virtualbox I can't copy to my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the client configuration, I was not setting the correct port. As can be seen in the above .conf file, the port required is **3128**.